# how to use css sprites?

Tags: css, sprite

I read somewhere that css sprites are better than using simple images. How is that ? also I am new to Html so can anyone tell me how css works and give me a simple example for css sprites?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Don't begin learning HTML and CSS with CSS sprites... Do you master `background-position` already?

Comment: No. @FelipeAls. can you tell me where to start with...

Comment: Learn HTML First. then CSS. then try to tackle Sprites. you might want to do Javascript before you try tackling sprites even?

Comment: @Malione is right you should go for the basics first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the complete code. Copy and paste in a notepad and save it as `abc.html`. Save the two images below in the same folder as:
`image.gif` for big one and `trans.gif` for small one.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Sprites</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        img.sprite
        {
            width:46px;
            height:44px;
            background:url(image.gif) 0px 0px;
        }        

        .sprite:hover
        {
            background: url(image.gif) 0px 44px;
        }
     </style>
</head>

<body>
    <img class="sprite" src="trans.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

- [image.gif on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8sKJ.gif)
- [trans.gif on imgur (1x1 pixels)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNjoI.gif)

In simple words, CSS sprites use only one image instead of many.
So instead of many image requests from server only a single request is sent.

Comment: Second image in my example is 1x1 pixel so i guess its lost in the background.

Comment: Ok. So i need a 1x1 pixel image for this example. I can make it photoshop.

Comment: yeah better do it... and also make sure that image is transparent.

Answer (score 5):

One trip to the server to get the images vs. multiple ones. 
I found  [SpritePad (online app)](http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/) for building them, it will also generate the relevant boiler plate css (which can be a bit messy if your're starting out).

Answer (score 1):

In basic terms - it allows you to load one image and use the said image on various elements around your page. Leading to less load requests and possibly load times.

Here's an example:
http://www.thedotproduct.org/experiments/css-sprites/

and here is the sprite image used:
http://www.thedotproduct.org/experiments/css-sprites/css-sprites-menu.jpg