# How to use one single png image to create multiple website buttons (and their hovers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Changing a color of a png image button on hover is a basic example for me to start with:

HTML `<a class="button" href="#" title="Trail Button (Dummy button)"></a>`

CSS `.button { display: block; float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: url('`#hover-img-url`') bottom; }`
`.button:hover {background-position: 0 0;}`

[example Jiddle for above code](http://jsfiddle.net/E6rNR/)

By using one single image (all buttons in one image), I want the same hover effect for all image buttons.
for example:
[Trail Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXR3k/): I used one 'arrow' button that is present inside a portion of a group image (image consisting of other buttons as well).

My Questions:

1. Is this a good way to implement or is there any other way to do this?
2. Is there any name with which we call this kind of single image helping for multiple image hovers?
3. It is difficult to select a portion of a image and use this portion as a button. Is there any other automated way to select Height and width of a portion of a image? If so, how to make use of that portion of a image (button) without loosing accuracy in the button hover effect?

Comment: http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/combine-images-css-sprites.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373162/how-to-use-css-sprites or http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/general-miscellaneous/css-sprite-example-and-tutorial/

Comment: It's called [Sprites](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=css+sprites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use image Sprites

Online generator with CSS markup included: http://www.spritecow.com/