# How use CSS sprites?

Tags: css, css-sprites

I'm trying to figure out how to use CSS Sprites on a sprite image with 4 sprites.

I have code to show the first two sprites. I have trouble with writing code to show the last two sprites. I am also unable to show the third and 4th sprites by themselves.

This is the image:
[image: Wrestling items]

How to show the last two?
How to show the 3rd and 4th sprite by themselves?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Show us some code, so we can help you better. Make some efforts before asking question.

Comment: I uploaded your image, so your question also makes sense should the image ever disappear from the server. I also cleaned up the language a bit. The image with sprites I called "image", the individual sprites "sprite".

To get help on this site you will likely need to demonstrate what you have done by sharing the code you have. It does not need to be great quality, just something to help the community understand what you have tried.

Comment: You can use [sprite generator](http://www.spritecow.com/)

Comment: [CSS Sprites: What They Are, Why They’re Cool, and How To Use Them](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use css sprites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373162/how-to-use-css-sprites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li id="belt-1"></li>
        <li id="belt-2"></li>
        <li id="belt-3"></li>
        <li id="belt-4"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}

.container ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container ul li {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBxX4.png);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 78px;
    background-size: auto 286px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.container ul li#belt-2 {
    background-position-y: 210px;
}

.container ul li#belt-3 {
    background-position-y: 123px;
    height: 58px;
}

.container ul li#belt-4 {
    background-position-y: 66px;
    height: 58px;
}
```

**Always Remember all images in CSS sprites, should have same canvas size**

I create a basic example of CSS sprites, I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example with the last two images. I recommend you to play around in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLsf692w/4/) with `.block`'s `width`, `height`, and `background-position`. The last two numbers in the `background` property allows you to define how many images will appear.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

.container .block {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBxX4.png) -85px -420px;
  width: 310px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">

  </div>
</div>
```

You can play around with it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLsf692w/4/)